# How can I implement a legend like the attached in victory?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, victory-charts

[image]

I am using victory to create charts, but VictoryLegend does not provide such kind of legend. Is there any existing react Legend component that can be used directly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a brief look at the docs it looks like victory does provide legends, [read more here](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-legend)

Here's a simple implementation from their docs:

```
<VictoryLegend x={125} y={50}
  title="Legend"
  centerTitle
  orientation="vertical"
  gutter={20}
  style={{ border: { stroke: "black" }, title: {fontSize: 20 } }}
  data={[
    { name: "One", symbol: { fill: "tomato", type: "square" } },
    { name: "Two", symbol: { fill: "orange", type: "square" } },
    { name: "Three", symbol: { fill: "gold", type: "square" } }
  ]}
/>
```

To create square shaped points specify type "square", other options are [listed here](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-primitives/#point).

> You can choose "circle", "diamond", "plus", "square", "star",
>   "triangleDown", "triangleUp"

Comment: This is not the one I attached here. It's circle.

Comment: you didn't specify in your question that you needed square points, I've updated my answer, please upvote and accept if it's helped you